# ¿Cómo obtener los elementos de una lista que no contengan valores nulos usando linq?

Tags: c#, linq, arraylist, datatable

Tengo un problema con la que he estado batallando, y es sobre un conjunto de datos que les presento en la captura.

Este son los datos que contiene la lista, que por ejemplo este no deberia de contarse ya que contiene nulos.

Definición de la lista, el orignen de datos en un datatable. entonces solamente tomo la matriz de esta.

```
var dTtemporal = datos.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToList();
```

Este es el código donde lo realizo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var Contados =  dTtemporal.Where( i => i.Any( y =>  y != null || y != DBNull.Value ||  !(y is System.DBNull) || (y.ToString().Length > 0) || (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y.ToString())) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.ToString()))) ).ToList();
```

Después de realizar los filtros los datos siguen igual, no descarta los registros con los valores nullos.

Pero de igual manera tengo otro filtro donde solamente tomo los valores con contengan valores nullos. este es el codigo.

```
 var Faltantes = dTtemporal.Where( i => i.Any(y => y == null || y == DBNull.Value || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y.ToString()) ) || i.Any( x => x is DBNull ))
                    .Select(r => new {
                        Producto    = r[6],
                        Folio       = r[7]
                    }).ToList();
```

Del cual si toma solamente los registro que contienen valores nullos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo, ¿cuál seria el error del código? solamente quiero tomar los registros que no contengan nullos. (El primer filtro).

Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es la definición de `dTtemporal`? Los datos no son *nullos* son *nulos* (una sola ele).

Comment: dtTemporal es una lista,

Comment: Genial. Una lista ¿de qué?

Comment: ya edite la pregunta, lo obtengo de una datatable, solamente selecciono la matriz que contiene el datatable, y lo guardo en dtTemporal

Comment: ¿Has probado `datos.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray.Where(o => o != null))`?

Comment: Es el mismo  efecto, sigue sin descartar los registros con valores nulos

Comment: Nulls o count =0?

Comment: @LucianoMontañez no entiendo, tu comentario

Answer (score 1):

La primera razón por la cual no funciona correctamente tu Linq es por qué estas tomando ciertos datos talcual están creadas sin valores.

```
var dTtemporal = datos.AsEnumerable()
```

Posterior a esto tomas todos los items y todas sus propiedades y los transformas a una lista con:

```
var dTtemporal = datos.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToList();
```

Esto crea la lista con todos los datos incluyendo los que no poseen ningun valor. Sin embargo se nota que unicamente quieres rescatar la propiedad 6 y 7.

Además tus filtros estan comparando a todo el objeto no a sus propiedades y esa es la razón por la cual no filtran el contenido.

Por lo tanto te recomiendo al inicio crear el objeto con las propiedades que necesitas y crear la lista solo con estas.

```
var dTtemporal = datos.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new {Prop1 = x[6], Prop2 = [7]}).Where(x => !String.isNullOrEmpty(x.Prop1)).Where(x => !String.isNullOrEmpty(x.Prop2)).ToList();
```